# image on html - cache

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a web page, which has an image. But the image is loaded some seconds after the page opens. I want to display a loading gif while the image has not been loaded, and then check if the image has been loaded every 2 seconds. Once the image has been loaded, I want to replace the loading gif with the image. I've written the following code:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function checkImage(src) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                // code to set the src on success
                $('#img1').attr('src', 'imageOriginal.jpg');
                $('#img1').removeAttr('width');
                clearInterval(interval);
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
                countErrors = countErrors + 1;
            };

            img.src = src; // fires off loading of image
        }
        var interval;
        var countErrors = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#img1').attr('width', '620px');
            interval = window.setInterval(function () { checkImage('imageOriginal.jpg?id=' + countErrors); }, 2000);
        });
    </script>

                <img borderstyle="solid" bordercolor="black" borderwidth="1px" id="img1" alt="Screenshot" style="max-width:620px;" src="loading.gif" />
```

It sometimes works, and sometimes don't. I even added an id parameter to prevent caching. But the loading gif is shown even if the image has already loaded. How do I solve this?

Comment: What's in @Model.FileResized and @Model.FileOriginal?

Comment: changed these strings for correct html

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is involved in your script, one way I've seen it done is by attaching an onload event to the image, similar to what you have there, except that the onload event triggers when the image is in fact loaded. Upon this event you could then hide the loading image.  I think it would make more sense to have the loading image be its own separate image and just hide/show it depending on whether your main image is loaded or not.

**Example:**

```
$('#img1').load(function() {
    $('#loadingImage').hide();
    $('#img1').show();
});
```

No need to have this check on an interval. The load event only needs to be attached once and will fire reliably when the image finishes loading.

Comment: the same problem. Image already exists, but load is not called yet... PS. Redesigned to the following - created an web-service, and call this web-service each X secs. It works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a floating element as a placeholder with your spinner in it, and on img.load (rather than onload) hide your floating div.  Using img.load will keep you from having to poll, and using a floating div will lessen any perceived 'hiccups' when transitioning between images.  Layering them also opens the door for animated transitions.